# WordPress admin pages redirecting to homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-security, wp-admin

i have an issue with **WordPress**. The site working pretty normal but on the **admin panel**, various pages like **edit post**, **installed plugins**, **add new plugin**, **add new page**, **settings**  redirects me to homepage. I'm googling like crazy for 3 days but i just found the mod_security issue. And it turned out useless for me too.

here is my .htaccess file

```
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond /home/gokkur/public_html/wp-content/sitemaps%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule \.xml(\.gz)?$ /wp-content/sitemaps%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    

    
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

Answer (score 1):

this is default content of WP `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Maybe your custom rewrite rules generating problems.